# The definition of a continuous semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators, nonlinear-analysis

Here is the definition of a continuous semigroup

Let $C$ be a subset of a Banach space $X$. A semigroup on $C$ is a group $\{S(t):t\geq 0\}$ of a self-maps defined on the subset $C$ which satisfies the following properties

- $S(0)=I,$
- $S(t+s)x=S(t)S(s)x, \forall t,s\geq 0,\; x\in C.$

A semi-group $S(t)$ is said to be continuous if
the mapping $h:[0, \infty) \times C \rightarrow C$ defined by $h(t,x)=S(t)x$ is continuous when the subset $C$ carries the norm topology of the element $x$.

What we mean by saying "$h(t,x)=S(t)x$ is continuous **when the subset $C$ carries the norm topology of the element $x$**"?

Comment: It means that $C$ bears the induces topology given by the norm on the Banach space, for the source set, they probably imply product topology